# Create links to java files in Doxia Apt site file?

Tags: maven, documentation, apt, maven-site-plugin, doxia

As part of our application development, we are creating documentation using the Maven site plugin.  Our apt files are located in `src/site/apt`.  I know one can make links in apt using {{xxx}} syntax, but I was wondering if there was an easy way to create a link to a java file and/or a package?

Is the only way to use relative paths (ie: ../../main/java/com/pkg/MyFile.java)?

Is there a way to link to a package name?

Answer (score 0):

you can use jxr plugin http://maven.apache.org/jxr/maven-jxr-plugin/ to get source as html in the generated site
then make links to xref/com/pkg/MyFile.html